# Using the Jpcap Library

Tags: java, capture, jpcap

I'm trying to develop a packet filtering software using Java and after some research I found out that its possible to use the JPCAP library to capture packets and apply the filter rules but I cant seem to get the jpcap library up and running. The link given netresearch.ics.uci.edu/kfujii/jpcap/doc/index.html isn't working anymore and the one on cnet isn't working (I can't import it).  It's giving the error:

```
package jpcap doesn't exist
```

Comment: The "package jpcap" sounds like your class path isn't configured correctly. I don't have more information though because I would guess a packet filtering library would be rather complex.

Comment: *"..in JAVA"*  1) No need to put tags in titles. 2) It is capitalized as 'Java'.  No need to SHOUT it from the roof-tops!

Comment: You could always search google: http://jpcap.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Also take note, this library is a JNI interface to a native library on the system.  You must have libpcap installed for jpcap to work.  There are Windows, OSX, and Linux versions of libpcap.